# Is there a difference in the actual meaning of these two sentences (average x mean)?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I'm really confused about if these two sentences actually mean the same, and if they're really interchangeable. I'm writing a scientific paper to be published in an Agronomy Journal.

"Mean fruit mass".
"Average fruit mass".

Looking for both sentences, for example, on Google Scholar, the sentence "average fruit mass" hits more results, although, to me, "mean fruit mass" sounds more correct.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: "Average" and "mean" basically mean the same thing.  (Or do they *average* the same thing? ;) )  The difference it that "average" is a little vague and could be interpreted to mean (imply) "median".

Comment: This depends totally on register. Outside the maths etc domain, 'average' defaults to 'mean' and is the more usual term. But in more precisionist registers, 'mean' is a hyponym of 'average', along with 'median', 'mode', perhaps 'midmark' (and possibly other statistics of central tendency).

Comment: For a scientific paper I would not use 'average'. In general conversation it means 'arithmetic mean' but to anyone who has any understanding of statistics (and most scientists do) 'average', unless you have previously said what sort of average, is more than a little ambiguous.The question is, of course, which sort of average you are talking about, I would have thought that the median fruit mass would the most useful.

Comment: I found this quote helpful: "1992   Independent 6 Jan. 18/7   *Even allowing for some element of skewness, all three forms of average—mean, median and mode—will be so close together as to make little difference."* It shows that the arithmetic mean is what is usually (loosely) called the average.

Comment: @Greybeard, the three numbers will **usually** be close together, but sometimes they won't be: **that's why** we have these three different concepts.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes -- I am aware. The point being that "average" is potentially ambiguous, but the other terms are not.

Comment: Why is this tagged "grammar"? I see no question about English syntax or about English morphology. Therefore it has nothing to do with grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly know the mean is calculated in the same way as the average: sum of *n* terms divided by *n*. But several variations, described in the source below, are used to prevent numbers, very high or low, from skewing the results. Though the *mean* is commonly called the *average* in conversation there are subtle reasons they are not identical. In your scientific paper it should be referred to as the *mean*. The reason that *average* shows up much more in searches is that it is the common *near* synonym, as well as being less likely to be confused with mean, as in a mean Mr. Mustard, who is certainly far from average.

https://sciencing.com/difference-between-mean-average-6461324.html

Comment: +1, but would you say _"average number of days to sell a product"_ or _"mean number of days to sell a product"_ ?

Comment: @Marco; Common usage may vary greatly from mathematical definition. No news there.

Answer (score 4):

This depends totally on register. Outside the maths etc domain, 'average' defaults to 'mean' and is the more usual term. But in more precisionist registers, 'mean' is a hyponym of 'average', along with 'median', 'mode', perhaps 'midmark' (and possibly other statistics of central tendency).

(answer by Edwin Ashworth, originally posted as a comment)